# How to send int16_t over TCP socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, stdint

How can a int16_t be transmitted safely on C++ TCP socket? In the following code, the server doesn't seem to receive the correct values and my guess is it's because htonl/ntohl are not defined for int16_t.

Client:

```
void client(int16_t value, int socket) {
    int16_t _value = htonl(value);
    write(socket, _value, sizeof(int16_t));
}
```

Server:

```
int16_t server(int16_t buf, int16_t value, int socket) {
    recv(socket,&buf,sizeof(int16_t));
    value = ntohl(buf);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: [`htobe16()` / `be16toh()`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/3/htobe16/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the Long versions `ntohl()` and `htonl()` when you should be using the Short versions `ntohs()` and `htons()`.

Pro tip: make sure you check the return value of write() and recv() (and consider using write() with read() or send() with recv() as those are the more usual pairings).